# Honeywell Chronotherm IV Plus thermostat

Tags: thermostat

The word "filter" is flashing on thermostat. The filter is clean. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual for your thermostat?

Comment: Generally there is a button press sequence or something in the manual that will let you know how to reset the filter timer.

Answer (score 2):

To reset the filter (which can be 30 days - 90 days depending on the vintage of the Chronotherm IV thermostat), press the `[I]` information button to display the filter days. (it will generally show `0` days remain).

Now press the TIME Up arrow (the one inside the lower door, not the temp up arrow on the outside) which will reset the filter time to `30` days and cancel the flashing filter message. (may reset days to `60` or `90` depending on model)

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The thermostat doesn't actually have a way to check your filter to see whether it is clean or not. The flashing "filter" turns on based on time - every 3 months. Resetting it (look in your manual) will make it start flashing in another three months.